# Embedding Jetty 9 and customizing Socket Address, Port and ThreadPool?

Tags: jetty, threadpool

I have previously used Jetty 8.1.14 as embedded web server in my application. Now I am trying to upgrade to version 9.2.10.

With Jetty 8, it was possible to specify the Host Address and Port using the setters in the "SelectChannelConnector" or "SslSelectChannelConnector", and also the ThreadPool as a constructor argument in the "Server" class.

Now, it seems one can only specify one or the other in the "Server" class. There are only constructor variants for the address and/or port, or the ThreadPool to use. I can't find any variant with all three arguments.

How can I specify all those parameters with Jetty 9?
I have tried:

```
String bindAddress = "myValue";
int port = 12345;
Server s = new Server(new InetSocketAddress(bindAdress, port));
```

and

```
ThreadPool t = MyHighlyCustomizedThreadPool();
Server s = new Server(t);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`ServerConnector`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html) for setting listen ports, setting listen host addresses, setting idle timeouts, and setting default protocols.  Once started, the same connector can be used to determine actual listening port (if using dynamically assigned ports), actual listen hosts (if using dynamic host addresses), etc ...

Use the [`HttpConfiguration`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpConfiguration.html) for setting buffers, secure identification (used for secure redirects), tweaking headers, powered by, server version announcement, etc..

Use [`ConnectionFactory`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ConnectionFactory.html) implementations to control how the progression of protocol selection should work with a recently accepted incoming connection. (Yes, this is a thing that is important in today's Web infrastructure)

For a basic example of HTTP/1.1 and SSL+HTTP/1.1 (aka HTTPS) see the [`ManyConnectors.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.10.v20150310/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyConnectors.java) embedded example

For an example of `ConnectionFactory` behavior with SPDY, see the [`SpdyConnector.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.10.v20150310/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/SpdyConnector.java) example *(note: SPDY has been deprecated in favor of HTTP/2 in Jetty 9.3.x)*

For an example of `ConnectionFactory` behavior with TLS + ALPN + HTTP/2, see the [`Http2Server.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/Http2Server.java) example *(note: you'll need Jetty 9.3.x for this)*