# Upgrading Jetty 8 to Jetty 9

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am upgrading from jetty 8 to jetty 9 and have come across some issues around compilation failures within some APIs.

The SslSelectChannelConnector has been removed and from what I can see httpConfiguration with secureRequestCustomizer replaces this.

But there are many methods that I cant find on both.  For example

setRequestBufferSize

setResponseBufferSize

setAcceptors

setMaxIdleTime

SessionHandler no longer has a getSessionManager() method.

Also the queueThreadPool no longer has a setMaxQueued(int ), and JettyServer no longer has these two methods:
setThreadPool(QueueThreadPool)
setGracefulShutdown(int)

Edit: SslSelectChannelConnector Deprecated.  use SelectChannelConnector with SslContextFactory.

```java
jettyServer.setThreadPool(threadPool);  // --> threadPool is set in the constructor new Server(QueueThreadPool)
jettyServer.setGracefulShutdown(5000);  // --> jettyServer.setStopTimeout(5000);
jettyServer.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });  // -->  ServerConnector which takes https_config
jettyServer.setSendServerVersion(false); // -->  https_config.setSendServerVersion(false);
```

Where or which API is used in place of the above?

Also is there any custom stuff that stopped working at runtime, that isn't obvious to find/see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reminder: Jetty versioning (since 1995) is `<servlet_support>.<major_version>.<minor_version>`

You are doing a major version upgrade from 8.1 to 9.4 (which is 6 major versions!).  You are seeing a massive amount of change as a result of this.

> The SslSelectChannelConnector has been removed and from what I can see httpConfiguration with secureRequestCustomizer replaces this.

Welcome to the new world of protocols.

There is no longer any concept of protocol specific connectors.

`ServerConnector` is the connector, it has no protocol knowledge, nor needs it.  It simply is a connection point (not even TCP/IP specific, it could be Unix Sockets for example) to the server.

The configuration of it, determines the connection type, where it binds, and how the protocol is negotiated once the client connects to that port.

The `ConnectionFactory` determines that.

The `HttpConfiguration` determines how the HTTP level behavior functions.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30191878/775715 for description.

See: [embedded-jetty examples](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.8.v20171121/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded) of this is use.  Start with [`LikeJettyXml.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.8.v20171121/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/LikeJettyXml.java).

See: [embedded-jetty-cookbook](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook) for more examples.

> But there are many methods that I cant find on both. For example
>
> setRequestBufferSize

This doesn't exist anymore, it was incompatible with SPDY and HTTP/2

See [`HttpConfiguration.setRequestHeaderSize(int)`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.8.v20171121/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpConfiguration.html#setRequestHeaderSize-int-) for controlling the maximum request header size.

*Note: If you are using HTTP/2, we would recommend that you do not adjust the request header size to be bigger then default (for protocol compatibility reasons).*

> setResponseBufferSize

This doesn't exist anymore, it was incompatible with SPDY and HTTP/2.

See [`HttpConfiguration.setResponseHeaderSize(int)`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.8.v20171121/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpConfiguration.html#setResponseHeaderSize-int-) for controlling the maximum response header size.

*Note: If you are using HTTP/2, we would recommend that you do not adjust the response header size to be bigger then default (for protocol compatibility reasons).*

See [`HttpConfiguration.setOutputBufferSize(int)`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.8.v20171121/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpConfiguration.html#setOutputBufferSize-int-) for output buffer aggregation controls. (has little meaning in HTTP/2, is really only relevant for HTTP/1.x)

> setAcceptors

See the various constructors for [`ServerConnector`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.8.v20171121/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html), there are no setters for these.

> setMaxIdleTime

There are *many* idle timeout settings available to you (eg: connector, connection, endpoint, thread, threadpool, AsyncContext, read, write, websocket session, etc ...)

Here's a few examples that seem relevant based on your questions.

See [`ServerConnector.setIdleTimeout(long)`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.8.v20171121/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractConnector.html#setIdleTimeout-long-)

See [`HttpConfiguration.setIdleTimeout(long)`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.8.v20171121/org/eclipse/jetty/server/HttpConfiguration.html#setIdleTimeout-long-)

See [`QueuedThreadPool.setIdleTimeout(int)`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.8.v20171121/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/QueuedThreadPool.html#setIdleTimeout-int-)

> SessionHandler no longer has a getSessionManager() method.

The Session Handling has undergone even greater change over the past 6 major version updates then the connectors.

See: [`OneServletContextWithSession.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.8.v20171121/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/OneServletContextWithSession.java)

> Also the queueThreadPool no longer has a setMaxQueued(int ), and JettyServer no longer has these two methods: setThreadPool(QueueThreadPool) setGracefulShutdown(int)

The configuration for min/max in [`QueuedThreadPool`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.8.v20171121/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/QueuedThreadPool.html) are part of the Constructors.  There are no setters for min/max.

To configure the [`Server`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.8.v20171121/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html) thread pool, use the constructors that allow you to pass in a Thread Pool.

*Note: If you are using HTTP/2, with html/css/javascript we would recommend that you plan for increased thread pool demand (due to the nature of the protocol)*